# C# Filestream Read - Recycle array?

Tags: c#, filestream

I am working with filestream read: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.read%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

What I'm trying to do is read a large file in a loop a certain number of bytes at a time; not the whole file at once. The code example shows this for reading:

```
int n = fsSource.Read(bytes, numBytesRead, numBytesToRead);
```

The definition of "bytes" is: "When this method returns, contains the specified byte array with the values between offset and (offset + count - 1) replaced by the bytes read from the current source."

I want to only read in 1 mb at a time so I do this:

```
using (FileStream fsInputFile = new FileStream(strInputFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) {

int intBytesToRead = 1024;
int intTotalBytesRead = 0;
int intInputFileByteLength = 0;
byte[] btInputBlock = new byte[intBytesToRead];
byte[] btOutputBlock = new byte[intBytesToRead];

intInputFileByteLength = (int)fsInputFile.Length;

while (intInputFileByteLength - 1 >= intTotalBytesRead)
{
    if (intInputFileByteLength - intTotalBytesRead < intBytesToRead)
    {
        intBytesToRead = intInputFileByteLength - intTotalBytesRead;
    }

    // *** Problem is here ***
    int n = fsInputFile.Read(btInputBlock, intTotalBytesRead, intBytesToRead); 

    intTotalBytesRead += n;

    fsOutputFile.Write(btInputBlock, intTotalBytesRead - n, n);
}

fsOutputFile.Close(); }
```

Where the problem area is stated, btInputBlock works on the first cycle because it reads in 1024 bytes. But then on the second loop, it doesn't recycle this byte array. It instead tries to append the new 1024 bytes into btInputBlock. As far as I can tell, you can only specify the offset and length of the file you want to read and not the offset and length of btInputBlock. Is there a way to "re-use" the array that is being dumped into by Filestream.Read or should I find another solution?

Thanks.

P.S. The exception on the read is: "Offset and length were out of bounds for the array or count is greater than the number of elements from index to the end of the source collection."

Comment: Are you just trying to copy one file to another?

Comment: when calling `fsOutputFile.Write`, your offset should be `0`, as this is the offset for the data in the array.  This should be `fsOutputFile.Write(btInputBlock, 0, n);`

Comment: and I don't see where `intTotalBytesRead` is declared, but that should start at `0`.  You should be able to reuse the same array with no trouble.

Comment: I changed that, ps2goat but still get an exception on the read:

"Offset and length were out of bounds for the array or count is greater than the number of elements from index to the end of the source collection."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you're incrementing intTotalBytesRead, which is an offset for the array, not for the filestream. In your case it should always be zero, which will overwrite previous byte data in the array, rather than append it at the end, using intTotalBytesRead.

```
int n = fsInputFile.Read(btInputBlock, intTotalBytesRead, intBytesToRead); //currently
int n = fsInputFile.Read(btInputBlock, 0, intBytesToRead); //should be
```

Filestream doesn't need an offset, every Read picks up where the last one left off.
See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.read(v=vs.110).aspx
for details

Answer (score 2):

Your code can be simplified somewhat

```
int num;
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
while ((num = fsInputFile.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
{
     //Do your work here
     fsOutputFile.Write(buffer, 0, num);
}
```

Note that `Read` takes in the **Array to fill**, the **offset** (which is the offset of the array where the bytes should be placed, and the (max) **number of bytes to read**.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Read` call should be `Read(btInputBlock, 0, intBytesToRead)`.  The 2nd parameter is the offset into the array you want to start writing the bytes to.  Similarly for `Write` you want `Write(btInputBlock, 0, n)` as the 2nd parameter is the offset in the array to start writing bytes from.  Also you don't need to call `Close` as the `using` will clean up the `FileStream` for you.

```
using (FileStream fsInputFile = new FileStream(strInputFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) 
{
    int intBytesToRead = 1024;
    byte[] btInputBlock = new byte[intBytesToRead];

    while (fsInputFile.Postion < fsInputFile.Length)
    {
        int n = fsInputFile.Read(btInputBlock, 0, intBytesToRead); 
        intTotalBytesRead += n;
        fsOutputFile.Write(btInputBlock, 0, n);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I can't believe I didn't see it. Glad this place exists.